# Combining OR with AND in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel 2016 which outputs a "Yes" if the following two conditions are met:

1. A2 value begins with 4 OR 9
2. A2 value length is 8

Otherwise output "No".

This is the formula I've come up with:

```
=IF(AND(OR(LEFT(A2;1)="4";LEFT(A2;1)="9");LEN(A2)="8");"Yes";"No")
```

Problem is, it just doens't work :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I really saw being an issue was the length returning an integer versus a string(ie, don't use quotes for that comparison).  I don't have 2016 to test on, but in 2013 this works properly:

```
=IF(AND(OR(LEFT(A2;1)="4";LEFT(A2;1)="9");LEN(A2)=8);"Yes";"No")
```

Comment: Semicolons in formula is a regional thing, but removing quotation marks from LEN fixed it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Edited to reflect semi-colon usage for your region